# Symfony2: Use Twig variable in stylesheet

Tags: symfony, twig

I include my stylesheet with a normal `<link />` tag, but I need/want to access to twig variables from inside the stylesheet. Is this possible?
THe only thing I imagine is putting the whole stylesheet into the document inside a `<style>` tag, but that won't be very pretty ;) .

Comment: You can't simply turn a CSS file in a twig file. There are many solutions, depending on the situation. What exactly would you like to do with your CSS ?

Comment: You don't need to put the whole stylesheet in a <style> tag, you can also do small css adjustments in a div tag like this: <div style="...">. Still not really pretty, but fast and simple.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a stylesheet, for instance `styles.css.twig` and put the content there. For instance:

```
.user-color{
    color: {{ user_color }};
}
```

Now, create a class which renders this file and saves it somewhere:

```
class TemplateRenderer
{
    protected $basepath;
    protected $templating;
    protected $parameters = array();

    public function __construct($templating, $basepath, $styleseheetpath)
    {
        $this->basepath = $basepath; /* "%kerel.base_path" parameter */
        $this->templating = $templating; /* "twig" service */
        $this->stylesheetpath = $stylesheetpath; /* custom defined parameter */
    }

    public function setParam($id, $value)
    {
        $this->parameters[$id] = $value;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        file_put_contents(
            $this->basepath.'/web/assets/css/styles.css',
            $this->templating->render(
                $this->stylesheetpath,
                $this->parameters
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Register this class as a service and register it as an after event listener (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html ).

From your controller (or from the event config file using method injection), you can call the `setParam` method to set a variable.

Inside your base html file, you can include this file using it's path (now, `web/assets/css/styles.css`).

**Please note** that the code is an example. Some error handling and caching is definitely needed to make this usable in production.